# Latin IME keyboard on android

Tags: android, keyboard, ime

Does anybody know if there is a way of using the standard Latin IME keyboard from an application?
Basically, I want this keyboard to be invoked whenever a textEdit is pressed, no matter in which handset the application is running...

any ideas?

Thanks in advance